# If taxonomy show class of active

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a nav which I would like to detect if an li should have a class of active or not.

I usually do this for a normal page like this:

```
    <li <?php if ( is_page('about')) { echo ' class="active"'; } ?>>
                            <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/about">About</a>
                        </li>
```

However I'm doing this on a taxonomy page and I would like to detect the name of the taxonomy term. So I have 4 terms, `design`, `illustration`, `motion` and `photography`.

How would I go about adding a class to the li of the active taxonomy term?

Here is what I have so far but its wrong:

```
<li <?php if ( is_taxonomy('illustration')) { echo ' class="active"'; } ?>><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?> /talcat/illustration">Illustration</a></li>
```

**Update:**

I have changed `is_taxonomy` to `is_tax` and then defining my taxonomy name and term. However this still isnt working. Here is my update coded:

```
<li <?php if ( is_tax( $Talcat, $illustration)) { echo ' class="active"'; } ?>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go and read [**Debugging in Wordpress**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), as this problem could be easily solved with debug set to true

[`is_taxonomy()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_taxonomy) was depreciated in version 3.0 already, and has been replaced with [`is_tax( $taxonomy, $term )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax)

You'll just need to specifiy your taxonomy and term in the parameters and you should be good to go

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have updated my question above as this still didnt seem to work.

Comment: O, you are the talcat man. As said in your previous question I answered, don't use capital letters in your name. Also `$Talcat, $illustration` should be `'Talcat', 'illustration'`. You should really set debug to true in wp-config.php :-)